# How to enter values from inputbox in excel and store them in newline using vbscript every time

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to add values from an InputBox to Excel worksheet cells which I have  created using VBScript.

I am able to store values in worksheet cells whenever I am entering the values in InputBox but my issue is that I have hardcoded the cell values and by using that I have assigned values to my InputBox that where to put the InputBox data in worksheet cells so whenever I am running my vbs file it is replacing the old values stored in those particular cells but instead I want to make it like every time I run my VBScript it will store the InputBox data in a new line and will also keep the old entries in worksheet cells saved but I am not sure how to do that.

Below is my code for your reference:

```
sInput = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput)

sInput1 = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\rrr.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

  objExcel.Cells(1,1).Value= sInput
  objExcel.Cells(1,2).Value= sInput1

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: this has been answered so many times ... please do some research

Comment: i did but was not able to find any specific answer or clue even i have tried some of the methods suggested by people regarding my issue but that also didn't help @jsotola

Comment: so you found no code that finds the next available empty row?

Comment: i found this one------ Sub RangeObjects()
   Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
   For i = 1 To 10
      For j = 1 To 5
         Cells(i, j).Value = i * j
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub-----
 but it is also not working  @jsotola

Comment: i have tried using it for assigning loop in cells so that it will select like cell (1,1) ,(1,2),(1,3)(1,4),(1,5) then it will go in (2,1) , (2,2) etc but it didn't work  @jsotola

Comment: sorry bro @jsotola but i am new in vbscripting i really do not have any idea instead of what i  said above

Comment: you do not have to know anything about coding to describe what happens when you run a program.

Comment: it is not running when i am entering that code to loop my cells. i just want to enter values from textbox in next line or row of cells in worksheet and to keep the old data saved instead of replacing them @jsotola

Comment: it looks to me like it multiplies numbers and puts them at top left of the worksheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this does what you are after.  You can adapt your code accordingly

```
Sub Test()

Dim rg As Range, lr As Long

Set rg = Sheet1.Range("A1")

lr = rg.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With rg
    .Offset(lr, 0).Value = "Me"
    .Offset(lr, 1).Value = "You"
End With
End Sub
```

In reference to your code:

```
Dim ws as worksheet
set ws = objWorkbook.Worksheets("Your Sheet Name")

dim rg as range
set rg = ws.range("A1")

Dim lr as Long
lr = rg.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With rg
  .Offset(lr, 0).Value = sInput
  .Offset(lr, 1).Value = sInput1
End With
```

Comment: it is working fine in vba but how to implement this vb scripting ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code which i have implemented and it is working fine

```
sInput = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput)

sInput1 = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\rrr.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True


Set rg = objExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

lr = rg.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With rg
    .Offset(lr, 0).Value = sInput
    .Offset(lr, 1).Value = sInput1 

End With


objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```